# PCIe TLP write packet address only 31:2 bits

Tags: cpu-architecture, pci-e

> Let's take a sample write packet :  Suppose that the CPU wrote the
>   value `0x12345678` to the physical address `0xfdaff040` using 32-bit
>   addressing
>
> [image: sample write packet]
>
> This example is from this [site](http://xillybus.com/tutorials/pci-express-tlp-pcie-primer-tutorial-guide-1) (*I didn't understand the explanations in the original post*)

1. Why does the address start at the second bit `[31 : 2]`
2. Why isn't the address the same

Comment: The address isn’t the same simply because of an inconsistency in the original between the diagram and the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An address of an aligned, 32-bit chunk always has two zero bits at the end of the address. You can think of this as either writing the address of the chunk to the 32-bit slot or as writing the addresses divided by four to bits 2 through 31 of the address. The result is the same either way since dividing by four is equivalent to shifting two bit positions to the right.

Comment: Saying in another way,  it's a (32b) **word address**, not a **byte address**.

Comment: And since at least 32b is sent, the byte enable words `first_be` and `last_be` are used to indicates which bytes are valid.